# incompatible pointer types when passing const variable

Tags: c, gcc

When I compile the following code, I got some compiler warning.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int global = 10;
void func_a(const int **pptr) {
    *pptr = &global;
}
void func_b(int *const *pptr) {
    **pptr = 20;
}
int main()
{
    int local = 30;
    int *ptr_1 = &local;
    const int *ptr_2 = &local;
    int* const ptr_3 = &local;
    func_a(&ptr_1); /* line 15 : compile warning */
    func_a(&ptr_2); /* line 16 : compile okay */
    func_a(&ptr_3); /* line 17 : compile warning */

    func_b(&ptr_1); /* line 19: compile okay? */
    func_b(&ptr_2); /* line 20: compile warning */
    func_b(&ptr_3); /* line 21: compile okay */

    return 0;
}
```

warnings :

```
a.c:15:12: warning: passing argument 1 of 'func_a' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
a.c:17:12: warning: passing argument 1 of 'func_a' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
a.c:20:12: warning: passing argument 1 of 'func_b' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
```

In my understanding, line 15 and 17 got compiler warning because `func_a()` does not want to modify `**pptr`. (i.e. the value of `local`).
And the compiler found that it is possible to modify the value via the pointer `ptr_1` or `ptr_3`.

Line 20 got compiler warning because `func_b()` does not want to modify `*pptr`. (i.e. the pointer).
And it is possible for `ptr_2` to change the pointer.

However, why line 19 would not get any compiler warning?
It is also possible for `ptr_1` to change the pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration `int *const *pptr` declares `pptr` to be a pointer to a constant *pointer* to a non-constant `int`.

That is, the function can change what `pptr` points to (`pptr = xxx`, rather useless), and you can change the value of the `int` (like you do in your code), but you can not change `*pptr` (`*pptr = yyy` is invalid).

Since you call the function with a a pointer to a pointer to a non-constant `int`, it's alright.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
func_b declare                 "a pointer to a constant pointer     to a non-constant" (int * const*).
line 19 invoke the func_b with "a pointer to a non-constant pointer to a non-constant" (int **).
Do you mean that the compiler think these two type are compatible?

Comment: @HPChen Yes those types are compatible. It's like having a function taking an `const int` argument, you can still pass a non-const plain `int` argument to that function. Or a function taking an `const int *` argument, you can still pass `int *` to it.

Comment: Yes, this makes me confused.
If "a function with `const int *` argument, and we pass `int *`" is right.
Then why line 15 "a function with `const int **` argument, we pass pass `int **`" got warning?

Comment: @HPChen With `const int **` you have a "pointer to `const int *`". With `int **` you have a "pointer to `int *`". That extra pointer indirection makes it a whole different type.